# My app is not supporting Android verision 4.4.4 or less

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-version

Here is my gradle.build (app)... My app is not supporting devices of Android version 4.4.4 or less. My 1st version was supporting all the devices but after I updated my SDK and Google Play Services, it's not supporting 4.4.4 or less. Previously my firebase version here was 9.0.0 but now I have changed it to 11.0.1 because firebase analytics was not working on it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'CSSkey'
        keyPassword 'romasa123'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/Romasa Khalid/AndroidStudioProjects/CSS.jks')
        storePassword 'romasa123'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "romasakhalid.css"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{       
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
}
```

Comment: Does it throw any error while running application in `4.4.4` or less than it ? It must be worked in this version. Check [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive ? How is your app not supported? Is it during the process you try to test the app ( minimum api .. is more than minsdk) or something ? or does it crash ? in lower sdk phones

Comment: it is in the play store .. when people try to install it ,it installs.. but doesnt works.. when open the app it shows unfortunately app is stop working ...

Comment: Then you need to check crash report in play store account. What the error contains in particular that version.

Comment: getting this error :/ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/romasakhalid.css-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/romasakhalid.css-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]